# Re-implement users in Wordpress with custom post types and fields

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I always find really difficult to work with users in Wordpress. So here's the question.

Let's say I want to use Wordpress to build a website with users and I don't want to use standard Wordpress users. I want my users, let's call them siteusers, to have multiple custom fields. I want them to have relationship with custom post types in my site.

For instance let's say I want to build a Spotify clone. I want my users to register, login, but also to create playlists, add songs to playlists, wishlists, etc. I want to have a logic behind this, and i want users to be able to download only songs they have access to.

My idea is to create a custom post type called "siteusers" and add custom fields to them and make a new frontend register/login/lostpassword/my account page/ machanism, different from the standard WP one. I would have to build an authentication method like i would on a rails application without devise.

Could it work, or are there wordpress limitations I am not seeing? Are anyone aware of any similar solution/plugin/tutorial that could save me some work?

Comment: You ask for an opinion of an idea you have. Could it work... My answer would be: Try, fail, retry, etc, success! Good luck

Comment: Off the top of my head, you'd want a CPT for songs, probably a custom taxonomy for the playlists. Rather than having a custom CPT for users and having to create all the associated pages and logic for that, why not just create a new user role, and add the additional fields you require as post meta?